# JBoss: only one persistence provider can be packaged with an application error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have a web application developed on Tomcat, but I need to switch it over to JBoss 7. When I try to run my server, I get the following error:

```
14:55:46,728 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."reportintegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."reportintegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "reportintegration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: only one persistence provider can be packaged with an application [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider, org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.deploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:65)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
... 5 more
```

After doing a lot of research it seems that JBoss has it's own Hibernate that it tries to use when run. I am not an expert with this stuff, so my question is do I still use my own Hibernate or theirs? For either, how would I go about that? Ideally, I could just tell JBoss to ignore theirs.

My persistence file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="DirectorDb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <description>Persistence unit for Oracle Connection</description> 
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> 

 <properties>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value=""/>   
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="150" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturned_connection_timeout" value="300" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debug_unreturned_connection_stack_traces" value="true" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements_per_connection" value="20" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.statement_cache_num_deferred_close_threads" value="0" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" /> 

 </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="DataSourceDb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <description>Persistence unit for SQL Server Connection</description> 
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> 

 <properties>

  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value=""/>   
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="1"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="150" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturned_connection_timeout" value="300" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debug_unreturned_connection_stack_traces" value="true" />  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements_per_connection" value="20" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.statement_cache_num_deferred_close_threads" value="0" />
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" /> 

 </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>reportintegration</groupId>
  <artifactId>reportintegration</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
<!--    <scope>provided</scope>   -->    
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet Context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was partially solved by deleting all references to my personal hibernate version in my pom.xml file. From there, JBoss was happy with just it's version existing.